# How to expand the Gmail folder in Postbox?

Tags: gmail, postbox

I have just installed Postbox and added my main Gmail account. All folders have been correctly synced so far, but I can't seem to be able to expand the [Gmail] folder:

[image]

If I go into the subscription options of the folder, however, I see all its subfolders:

[image]

So Postbox does indeed see the subfolders correctly, but I can't view them from the main application pane. How can I make the [Gmail] folder behave like other folders which contains subfolders?